# Regex - Removing Dollar Sign From Text Input

Tags: javascript, html, regex, onkeyup

I have a the following onkeyup command to test for, and remove, letters commas and dollar signs:

```
onkeyup="if (/(?:[a-zA-Z]|\s|,|\$)+/ig.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/(?:[a-zA-Z]|\s|,|\$)+/ig,'')"
```

It works for everything except for the dollar signs.

Can anybody help me out here?

Thanks,
Brds

Comment: This actually seems to work correctly for me as it is., but the regex can be much simpler: `/[a-z\s,$]/ig` unless I misunderstand you.  http://jsfiddle.net/skM5N/3/

Comment: Works for me... Try dumping `this.value` to the console and seeing what's there.

Comment: It would probaby be less expensive to just run the replace without the test.

Comment: Looks like it's working to me: http://jsfiddle.net/wb4zG/

Comment: @Michael: also, the preliminary `if (...)` check is not necessary...

Answer (score 3):

**HTML** interprets your backslash as escaping the inline html string, not the regex.  The following code prints `$`.

```
<body onload='alert("\$");'> // prints '$', not '\$'
```

You need to escape twice, or move the regex out of the inline html and into a function.

I believe the correct answer is replace `\$` with `\\$`, as follows:

```
onkeyup="if (/(?:[a-zA-Z]|\s|,|\\$)+/ig.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/(?:[a-zA-Z]|\s|,|\$)+/ig,'')"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to clean up an arbitrary string into just a number, you'll chase less edge cases by replacing everything that isn't a digit (assuming you want an integer) with the empty string.

```
this.value = this.value.replace( /[^0-9]/, '' );
```